# My macro compares and pastes data to the specified column. I want it to compare and paste the data in the next empty column

Tags: vba, excel

[[The sheet from where the data is to be copied, columnB2:B]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Fyy.jpg)

[As columnB is filled I want the data in Sheet1 ColumnB to be copied to the next empty column in Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faxDC.jpg)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLM6b.jpg)

My macro compares and pastes data to the specified column. I want it to compare and paste the data in the next empty column.In the line "If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("B" & FR).Value = c.Offset(0, 1)" I want "B" to be emptyColumn but I am not able to do that.

```
Sub UpdateW2()

    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, FR As Long
    Dim emptyColumn As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set w1 = Sheet1
    Set w2 = Sheet2

    emptyColumn = w2.Cells(2, w2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If emptyColumn > 1 Then
        emptyColumn = emptyColumn + 1
    End If

    For Each c In w1.Range("B2", w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        FR = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("B" & FR).Value = c.Offset(0, 1)
    Next c

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "*I want it to compare and paste the data in the next empty column*" "*I want "B" to be emptyColumn but I am not able to do that*". Are you trying to paste in the next empty column? Or the column B, not sure what you want here

Comment: Also, I noticed in your code on the line your questioning, it's missing an `End If` statement. Maybe that's the issue to your problem here?

Comment: @Maldred I want it to paste it in the next empty column.

Comment: @Maldred My problem lies in the line "If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("B" & FR).Value = c.Offset(0, 1)". I want "B" to be written as emptyColumn

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: @peakpeak I added images. If you could help me now I would be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 emptyColumn = w2.Cells(2, w2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 If emptyColumn > 1 Then
       emptyColumn = emptyColumn + 1
 End If
```

This returns the  column in row 2 for which there are no entries to the right. What you want (I think) is the first column to not hold any data at all)

```
 emptycolumn = w2.usedrange.columns.count +1
```

Comment: My problem lies in the line "If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("B" & FR).Value = c.Offset(0, 1)". I want "B" to be written as emptyColumn

Comment: "If FR <> 0 Then w2.cells( FR,emptycolumn).Value = c.Offset(0, 1)"

Comment: If this solved your issue, please mark it as answered